# When running with Bazel, where should I save .pb graphs for Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, cpu, x86-64, bazel

Directory structure:

```
~/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/dnnops/
├── BUILD
├── graph.pb
└── main.cc
```

The failing code line from `main.cc`: `status = ReadBinaryProto(tf::Env::Default(), "graph.pb", &graph_def);`. Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/cjweeks/tensorflow-cmake/tree/master/examples/install-project).

Bazel output:

> WARNING: /home//.cache/bazel/_bazel_rd1/4ab077b6e1a2076b6ea9f23b417088a6/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE:1: Workspace name in /home//.cache/bazel/*bazel*/4ab077b6e1a2076b6ea9f23b417088a6/external/protobuf_archive/WORKSPACE (@com_google_protobuf) does not match the name given in the repository's definition (@protobuf_archive); this will cause a build error in future versions
>   INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/cc/dnnops:dnnops (0 packages loaded).
>   INFO: Found 1 target...
>   Target //tensorflow/cc/dnnops:dnnops up-to-date:
>     bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/dnnops/dnnops
>   INFO: Elapsed time: 5.378s, Critical Path: 5.04s
>   INFO: 2 processes, local.
>   INFO: Build completed successfully, 3 total actions
>
> INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/dnnops/dnnops
>   Not found: graph.pb; No such file or directory
>   ERROR: Non-zero return code '1' from command: Process exited with status 1

**What I tried**

Copy the same graph file inside `bazel-bin/tensorflow/cc/dnnops`. Still fails with same output from Bazel.

**Question**

How should I expose the graph file location to Tensorflow/Bazel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly oversight... I entered the **full path**. From this:

`status = ReadBinaryProto(tf::Env::Default(), "graph.pb", &graph_def);`

To this:

`status = ReadBinaryProto(tf::Env::Default(), "/home/<user>/path/to/graph.pb", &graph_def);`